# Where will be create a new file in java, when path is not given?

Tags: java, file

In java,

```
File f;
f = new File("myfile.txt");
if (!f.exists()) 
{
    f.createNewFile();
}
```

when excute the above code,which path is assigned in default, while specific path is not given?

Comment: Did you try executing it and see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current directory, which you can get by calling:

```
new File('.').getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: getAbsolutePath() may give a friendlier result on unix systems as getCanonicalPath() resolves symlinks... this may give odd results such as converting /home/me to an odd path such as: /mnt/server/dsk/homedirs/m/mydir

Comment: Fair enough. Though for most/all purposes, it shouldn't matter if you're using the canonical or absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

The current directory.

Answer (score 2):

The current directory. Apparently `System.getProperty("user.dir")` can get this for you.

Comment: Just as a somewhat unrelated warning: don't try to set that property, it will behave strangely ;-)