# where is myfile after createNewFile()

Tags: java, createfile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where will be create a new file in java, when path is not given?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333046/where-will-be-create-a-new-file-in-java-when-path-is-not-given)

I am trying to create a txt file in the current directory. I ran the code below and there was no error. But I couldn't find the myfile.txt anywhere. I want to create the myfile.txt in the current directory. How can I do that?

The code that I used:

```
public void createFile(){
        try{
            File f = new File("myfile.txt");
            if (!f.exists()){
                f.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("New file \"myfile.txt\" has been created");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error while creating file " + e);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: That's what it does. I suggest you print your cwd. `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: why not just write the whole path where you want to store?

Comment: All this will do is create an empty file. If you want to put something in the file you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing this on the console:

```
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

That will tell you for sure.

Answer (score 4):

It's in the user directory, which can be retrieved with:

```
 System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

See here for details:

[In Java, what is the default location for newly created files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154529/in-java-what-is-the-default-location-for-newly-created-files)